# jQuery - ajax doesn't send request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have following piece of code:

```
$("#profileImageButton").click(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var cid = id.split('_')[1];

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Profile/SetProfile",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { id: cid },
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert("BEFORE!");
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            $(".bodyContentNotification").show();
            $(".bodyContentNotification").text(data.responseJSON.msg);
            $(".bodyContentNotification").attr("id", "WarningNotification");
        }
    });
});
```

This is extremly simple code, but something is wrong. When I click button, chrome debugger catches breakpoins at beforeSend (and to be sure, I alert message), message shows and nothing happens. Fiddler doesn't catch any event and I think, ajax() doesn't send request. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: loot at the network tab of chrome developer tools

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, though, i bet jshint could have told you that.

Comment: Chrome doesn't show any messages. But I noticed, that webpage is reloading when I click alert button OK.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error!

You're targeting an element with the ID `profileImageButton`.
On the first line you're doing `this.id`, which is still `profileImageButton`.
On the next line after that you're using `id.split('_')[1];`, but there is no `[1]` in that array as there is no underscore in that ID, and that's an error.

Comment: How do you get the second index in an array that has no second index. The ID clearly has no underscore ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try place jQuery send button inside forum markup. I wrote something like this in code:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
    ...
    <button id="profileImageButton"></button>
</form>
```

profileImageButton - click on this fires click event, in which i try send ajax get request. THIS IS WRONG to put this inside form-post.

Comment: there's nothing wrong about doing this, you just have to code appropriately for it, for example, by preventing the default action or the submit event.

Comment: In my case, that was an error generator. Thanks for answers, problem solved.

Comment: It's not an error generator per se, it's just that a button has a default type of "submit", hence submitting the form, and if you knew the basics, you'd know that, and use `type="button"` or something similar to avoid it. BTW, I still stand by my answer, you have an error.